# Adding values in associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php. This is my code

```
    $retval = $conn->query("Select points from evaluation_log where session_id='{$sessionid}';");
    $result=array();
    $temp=array();
    while($record = $retval->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $result[]= $record;
        }
```

The purpose of this query is to return multiple points against an id from the database which i'm storing in an array. Now I want to take sum of these points in the array. How should I do that.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: Just use `SELECT SUM(points)..` in query

Comment: You should be parametrising the $sessionid variable

Comment: yup, a SUM query never crossed my mind. thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely must use your example then this would work:

```
$retval = $conn->query("select points from evaluation_log where session_id='{$sessionid}'");

$sum = 0;

while($record = $retval->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    $sum+= $record['points'];
}

echo $sum;
```

---

However, this should be simpler:

```
$retval = $conn->query("select sum(points) as sum_points from evaluation_log where session_id='{$sessionid}'");

$record = $retval->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $record['sum_points'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will be more optimum use group_concat and array_sum

```
    $retval = $conn->query("Select group_concat(points separator ',') as points from evaluation_log where session_id='{$sessionid}';");
    $result=array();
    while($record = $retval->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))   // while loop only once by using group_concat
        {
            $result[]= explode(',',$record);
        }
   $sum_of_points = array_sum($result);
   echo $sum_of_points;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use SUM function in you MySQL query that you will get in array.